# Efficient way to display data

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app that has a fragment where a user can open a spinner using a button and select a food item. The food item will then be displayed under the button in a list. I have tried creating textviews and making invisible textviews and setting the text later, but none have worked. I was wondering if anyone knew of a better way of creating this that I'm not seeing.

[image: screenshot]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.lastineindustries.ingredismartv2.Kitchen">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:text="Add An Ingredient"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/valueButton"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nested LinearLayouts definitely aren't good... Can you draw a picture of what you actually want to show?

Comment: *The food item will then be displayed under the button in a list*... 
ListView and ArrayAdapter were built for this purpose, not a dynamic LinearLayout

Comment: Do I still use TextViews edited in the code?

Comment: That depends if you want a custom Adapter or not. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

[image]

Then, read my code.

1. code of `ChooseFoodFragment.java` and its layout file:

   ```
   public class ChooseFoodFragment extends Fragment{

       @Nullable
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose_food, container, false);
           initViews(v);
           return v;
       }

       private Button btn_add;
       private ListView listView;
       private List<String> mData = new ArrayList<>();
       private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;


       private void initViews(View v) {
           listView = v.findViewById(R.id.list);
           mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mData);
           listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

           btn_add = v.findViewById(R.id.add);
           btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   ChooseFoodDialog dialog = new ChooseFoodDialog();
                   dialog.setOnSelectedListener(new ChooseFoodDialog.OnSelectedListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onSelected(String name) {
                           mData.add(name);
                           mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// update the list of selected food
                       }
                   });
                   dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");//show the spinner items to select
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

`fragment_choose_food.xml`,just remove other views except the root view and the button, then add a ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lastineindustries.ingredismartv2.Kitchen">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Add An Ingredient"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

2. the code of `ChooseFoodDialog.java` and its layout file.

   ```
   public class ChooseFoodDialog extends DialogFragment {

       @Nullable
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_choose_food, container, false);
           initViews(v);
           return v;
       }

       private ListView lv;
       private List<String> mData = new ArrayList<>();

       private void initViews(View v) {
           // prepare some temp data
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
               mData.add("Ingredients_" + i);
           }

           lv = v.findViewById(R.id.lv_ingredients);
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mData);
           lv.setAdapter(adapter);
           lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                   String ingredient = mData.get(i);
                   if (mListener != null) {
                       mListener.onSelected(ingredient);// when the item of food is selected
                   }
                   dismiss();
               }
           });

       }

       private OnSelectedListener mListener;

       public void setOnSelectedListener(OnSelectedListener listener) {
           mListener = listener;
       }


       interface OnSelectedListener {
           void onSelected(String name);
       }
   }
   ```

`dialog_choose_food.xml`,that's simple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_ingredients"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

3. run the program, check it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ListView` or `RecyclerView` for such tasks. Check out example from official Android documentation: [link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).